# Image Replacement <a> tag not showing up in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text-indent

I am trying to get this image replacement done for a quick under construction page. They gave me and image to use and they wanted me to just put link hotspots over two areas on the image. This works in all browsers except IE and I don't know why...I do know when I un-comment the borders I get the finger icon on the red border...Any ideas?

Here is the CSS:

```
#container {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1177px;
```

}

```
.account {
display: block;
width: 103px;
height: 31px;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 241px;
/*border: solid 1px red;*/
```

}

```
.brochure {
display: block;
width: 208px;
height: 280px;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 421px;
left: 478px;
/*border: solid 1px red;*/
```

}

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">    
<h1><a class="account" href="#">account view</a></h1>
<h1><a class="brochure" href="http://public.faulknermediagroup.com.s3.amazonaws.com/LPL/UnderConstruction/Kimball/KimballCreek_D.Bennion_BroB_Rnd7.pdf" target="new">brochure</a></h1>
<img src="kcp-underconstruction.jpg" width="1177" height="1129" alt="" />
```

Comment: What do you want? Could you **please clarify** the desired output and the actual issue? You want to image to be a link?

Comment: You get the finger because that is the default cursor for an Image. With regard to your earlier query have u checked the size of the img tag? it is probably occupying the full page..

Comment: Why not simply use an image [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map), since this would seem to be precisely their use-case.

Comment: @AnaMaria The default cursor for an image is the default cursor of the OS, unless it's contained in an anchor element.

Comment: Also, what is the height of `.brochure` supposed to be? 31px or 280px? And why do the `<a>`s need to be in `<h1>`s? By the way, this technique has preciously little to do with image replacement.

Comment: Fixed. You have to use a ridiculous old school hack for this to work with IE 8 and 9. Had to make a 1x1 pixel empty GIF and set it as the background of the <a> and repeat. Also, good catch @Mr Lister, I was copying and pasting, and not paying much attention in regards to the widths and heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with IE is that you shift the text in the links out of the way with `text-indent`. Then the links themselves are empty or text, so IE thinks the user is no longer supposed to click on them.

So the solution is to leave the text in the right place, just make it invisible by giving it an opacity of 0.

In other words, use this CSS:

```
#container {
 position: relative; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1177px;
}

.account {
 font-size:31px; line-height:1;
 opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);
 width: 103px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 241px;
 /*border: solid 1px red;*/
}

.brochure {
 font-size:280px; line-height:1;
 opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 421px;
 left: 478px;
 width: 208px;
 /*border: solid 1px red;*/
}
```

As you can see, I make the font size as high as the block size originally was, to make sure to fill the whole block vertically. Oh, and I don't need `display:block`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. However, tsdexter's answer works too, and is better in many ways.

Comment: Yes I remember using image maps. I actually should use it now that I think of it since this was such a silly task to be doing in the first place, but I already went ahead with yours. But tsdexter did bring up a great solution, which I had completely forgotten about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you just use an image map and be done with it.

```
<div id="container">    
    <img usemap="#map" src="http://public.faulknermediagroup.com.s3.amazonaws.com/LPL/UnderConstruction/Kimball/kcp-underconstruction.jpg" width="1177" height="1129" alt="" />

    <map id="map" name="map">
        <area shape="rect" alt="" title="Account View" coords="831,2,935,33" href="#" target="" />
        <area shape="rect" alt="View Brochure" title="View Brochure" coords="477,420,687,703" href="http://public.faulknermediagroup.com.s3.amazonaws.com/LPL/UnderConstruction/Kimball/KimballCreek_D.Bennion_BroB_Rnd7.pdf" target="" />
    </map>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsdexter/hnSxs/1/

Bonus: Include rwdimagemaps and now it's responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsdexter/hnSxs/2/

Comment: Thank you, I had completely forgotten about image maps.

Comment: No worries @JamesAugustavo

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above. text indent can have strange outcomes

I really like the following image replacement from: 
http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/

```
     .brochure{
         background-color: transparent;
         border: 0;
         color: transparent;
         font: 0/0 a;
         text-shadow: none;
         //and your other styles without overrriding the above ones.
         display:block;
         width: 103px;
         height: 31px; 
      }
```